# My app is in live, but certificate is expiring on this month end(Does it affect my production app).Shall I renew and need to submit new app?

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-push-notifications, app-store

My app is in live in Appstore. Does it affect anything?

Questions:

1. How can I generate certificate before expiry?
2. If I revoke that certificate does it will raise any issue in the live app?
3. Shall I need to upload any builds while renewal of this certificate?
4. How the push notification certificates are handled?

Can I able to renew this or shall i need to create any new certificate with the same bundle Id?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not affect the actively live app.

2. If you revoke the certificate it's totally fine, just provision another. I usually provision a new certificate every time I upload an app and have never had any issues, just be sure to delete the old ones.
3. For good measure I would upload a new build with it
4. Push certificates are tied to a Distribution Certificate so you will need to provision another one as well.

TL;DR Apple's certificates are an absolute pain, but they are more forgiving than you might think (and I initially thought). You can delete and re-provision without any effect to your live app, I've done it tons of times.

Comment: For [3] Means a new release of your app?

Comment: Sorry, no new release. Changing the certificate while the app is live will not affect the app. It will just mean you need a new release for the next release lol

Answer (score 2):

**1. How can I generate certificate before expiry?**

**Ans:** You can renew it after expiry instead of generating new one. A distribution certificate is valid for one year from date of issue. After it expires, you won’t be able sign and install apps on your devices although this will not affect any existing apps in the App Store.

**2. If I revoke that certificate does it will raise any issue in the live app?**

**Ans:** No, this will not affect any existing apps in the App Store.

**3. Shall I need to upload any builds while renewal of this certificate?**

**Ans:** Not required

**4. How the push notification certificates are handled?**

**Ans:** The push notification certificate is not part of the application build. Therefore for push to continue working you only have to create a new certificate and deploy the p12 file at your server. You don't have to submit a new version of your app.